# Exclude certain paths from Devel::Cover's coverage report

Tags: perl, testing

We've got a lot of shared libraries in our project which reside under specific path (but not in Perl's default @INC).

By default, `cover -t` would report coverage on both the modules being tested and our common modules. I only need coverage figures on the modules I'm developing.

I've tried adding the path to the --ignore_re, but it didn't help.

So the question is: is there a way to exclude a module path from coverage test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar bug report was submitted for [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aCover): [summary, report total from cover tool includes ignored files](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=68517)

Comment: Ah, so I should have looked not only into the docs, but into bugtracker as well. Thanks.